# Coq type error when matching with type family

Tags: coq

I’m trying to re-implement an example from [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) from memory. I wrote:

```
Inductive myType : Set := MyNat | MyBool.

Definition typeDenote (t : myType) : Set :=
  match t with
    | MyNat => nat
    | MyBool => bool
  end.

Inductive unaryOp : myType -> myType -> Set :=
| Twice : unaryOp MyNat MyNat.

Definition twice (n:nat) : nat := n + n.

Definition tunaryDenote (a b : myType) (t : unaryOp a b)
    : typeDenote a -> typeDenote b :=
  match t with
  | Twice => twice
  end.
```

The resulting error is:

```
Toplevel input, characters 125-130
>   | Twice => twice
>              ^^^^^
Error: In environment
a : myType
b : myType
t : unaryOp a b
The term "twice" has type "nat -> nat" while it is expected to have type
 "forall H : typeDenote ?141, typeDenote ?142"
```

I don’t understand this error message. I would think that once the match on `Twice : unaryOp MyNat MyNat` succeeds, Coq infers that `a` and `b` are `MyNat`s, and thus `typeDenote a -> typeDenote b ≡ nat -> nat`, making `twice` a perfectly fine candidate for the return value. Where’d I go wrong?

Comment: Your analysis at the end looks perfectly fine, so I've tried your piece of code exactly as it is, but Coq didn't complain at all (checked with Coq v8.4pl6 and v8.5pl2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @AntonTrunov said, it is typechecked without any issue on my Coq 8.5pl1. However if you need to add some extra annotations for your version to accept the function, you want to [have a look at this section of the manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual020.html) to figure out what to do.

My guess is that you want to have a `match ... in ... return ... with` to say that the return type should be *refined* by the information obtained by matching t at the type `unaryOp a b` (indeed: `a` and `b` will take concrete values in the `Twice` branch).

This is the definition you get using that technique:

```
Definition tunaryDenote (a b : myType) (t : unaryOp a b)
    : typeDenote a -> typeDenote b :=
  match t in unaryOp a b return typeDenote a -> typeDenote b with
  | Twice => twice
  end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is that Coq's type inference is limited, and does not do the reasoning you want it to do.

Coq's type inference does not do arbitrary calculation but simple unification. It looks at `twice`, understand that it is `nat->nat` and concludes that it is not (syntactically) of the form `typeDenote a -> TypeDenote b`.

If it was doing calculation, it was likely to be non-terminating, since its type system is very sophisticated so you can encode non-trivial computation there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a newer version of Coq, and like others have said, it typechecks without issue on Coq 8.5. :)